# Google Calendar API Authorization asked all the time

Tags: authorization, google-calendar-api

My question is quite simple, I'm using Google Calendar API with a php script.

My script is working but I can't run it with a cron because I need to authorize my app all the time.

Is there any way to do what I want ?

Here's my code :

```
<?php
require_once 'google/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");
$client->setClientId([MY APP ID]);
$client->setClientSecret([MY SECRET TOKEN]);
$client->setRedirectUri([MY REDIRECT URI]);
$client->setDeveloperKey([MY DEV KEY]);
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

/*
** Request token from API
*/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {


  // MY CODE GOES HERE


  } else {

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}


?>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have an answer to this problem yet, but I had this same problem once.  Google Api returns an Oauth access token.  This token lasts indefinitely, but in your code you are storing it in $_SESSION variable, which has a time span on which it will keep.  Try using `$token = $client->getAccessToken();` in order to put the access token into a variable, then store the token in some other form, such as database.  Then when checking if `$_SESSION['token']` is set, if it is not, you can query your database to retrieve the token and use `$client->setAccessToken($queryResult);`  The API takes care of the rest as long as you have that access token.